# How do i reference the objects created in the XML from the main .java program?

Tags: android, motorola-droid

I am creating an android app using Eclipse. This is my first program using either eclipse or writing for android. I have created several objects in my XML (4buttons and a text-View). The program is supposed to display a random result in the text-View when one of the buttons are pressed. There is no problems with the code to determine the random result, but I cannot find how to reference the objects so as to edit the text-View or connect the buttons to the functions I have made. How do i reference the objects created in the XML from the main .java program?

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
R.layout.main   // layout with "main" id
R.string.hello  // string with "hello" id
R.id.button     // button with "button" id
```

If you want to get a view, a button for example:

```
Button launch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```